# Jenkins and Kubernetes integration localhost

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I'm newly learning kubernetes with my own interested i have one master and worker node both are up & running in my Ubuntu box.

```
root@poc:~# kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1     <none>        443/TCP          2d

root@poc:~# kubectl get nodes
NAME          STATUS    ROLES    AGE    VERSION
poc-worker2   Ready    <none>   6m3s   v1.17.0
poc.com       Ready    master   2d     v1.17.0

root@poc:~# kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1     <none>        443/TCP          2d

root@poc:~# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://10.0.0.4:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://10.0.0.4:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy


root@poc:~# docker -v
Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d


root@poc:~# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:20:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:12:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Now the question is when i am running my jenkins with below pod template to build Ng-8 application

```
def label = "worker-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"

podTemplate(label: label, containers: [
  containerTemplate(name: 'nodejs', image: 'nodejscn/node:latest', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat'),
  containerTemplate(name: 'docker', image: 'docker', command: 'cat', ttyEnabled: true),
  containerTemplate(name: 'kubectl', image: 'bitnami/kubectl:latest', command: 'cat', ttyEnabled: true)

],
volumes: [
        hostPathVolume(hostPath: '/var/run/docker.sock', mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'),
        hostPathVolume(hostPath: '/root/.m2/repository', mountPath: '/root/.m2/repository')
]) {
  node(label) {
    def myRepo = checkout scm
    def gitCommit = myRepo.GIT_COMMIT
    def gitBranch = myRepo.GIT_BRANCH
    def shortGitCommit = "${gitCommit[0..10]}"
    def previousGitCommit = sh(script: "git rev-parse ${gitCommit}~", returnStdout: true)

    stage('Test') {
      try {
        container(nodejs) {
          sh """
            pwd
            """
        }
      }
      }
    }
}
```

when i trigger the build my jenkins job is getting failed with below error.

```
Jenkins Output
#############
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node

Still waiting to schedule task
‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘worker-241e848a-e47b-4736-9f1d-b4d785c8be73’
```

can you please some help me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you using docker plugin? Did you check this thread: https://gitmemory.com/issue/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/574/500787315 ?

Comment: Hi Pjoter, Of course i'm using docker plugin.

Comment: What is version of that plugin? Are you sure that Jenkis configuration is good? It might be missconfiguration like here; https://gitmemory.com/issue/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/574/500787315?